# zend-framework navigation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-navigation

i have this xml file for  Creating a container ,
if i want create a db for save this items and and create container from db 
how should i do ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<config>
    <nav>
        <logout>
            <label>logout</label>
            <controller>authentication</controller>
            <action>logout</action>
            <resource>logout</resource>

        </logout>


        <login>
            <label>login</label>
            <controller>authentication</controller>
            <action>login</action>
            <resource>login</resource>

        </login>
        <test>
            <label>test</label>
            <uri>#</uri>
            <resource>test</resource>
            <pages>
                <list>
                    <label>list</label>
                    <controller>tset</controller>
                    <action>listtest</action>
                </list>

                <archive>
                    <label>archive</label>
                    <controller>myarchive</controller>
                    <action>archive</action>
                </archive>
            </pages>
        </test>
      </nav>
</config>
```

and code in bootsrap

```
$navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . 'navigation.xml', 'nav');

$navContainer = new Zend_Navigation($navContainerConfig);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to store this in database?

If you really need, the best way is nested set.

You may also just `serialize` the array and save to the database.

You may also use `Zend_Config_Xml_Writer` instead of the database.